# Calculating how often coordinates fall within a certain perimeter?

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples, counter

I am meant to imagine that i have an empty 100*100 array and that there a several thousand random locations/coordinates within this array. I need to calculate how many of these coordinates lie within 15 pixels of the 'straight' edges. So far i have this code...

```
import random
import pylab
import numpy                            #all import statements
pylab.close("all")

x = [(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(3000)]      #creating list of x coordinates
y = [(random.randint(0,100)) for j in range(3000)]      #creating list of y coordinates
array=zip(x,y)                                                  #creating an array by combining the x and y coordinates
                                #end of part 1a
counter = 0                         #start of 1b
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        if i<=15 or i>=85:
                        if array[i][j]>0:
                                counter=counter+1
        elif j<=15 or j>=85:
                        if array[i][j]>0:
                                counter=counter+1

print counter,"random locations within 15 pixels of the edges"
```

How can i correct the code? Currently i get an error reading saying 'tuple index out of range' I know its reffering to the if array[i][j]>0 line but i dont understand whats wrong with it...

Comment: `zip` may not be doing what you think.  It's not creating a 100 x 100 array, rather a list of 100 (x,y) tuples.

Comment: so how can i correct it either so it is an array or so that the counter looks at the tuples?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You're generating a sparse grid of values. If you iterate over those tuples by placing them in a dictionary first you can just check each of the discrete locations for edge violations. Below is a working example.

```
edge_dist = 15
sparse_grid = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x,y in zip(x,y):
    sparse_grid[(x,y)] += 1
for i,j in sparse_grid:
    if (i <= edge_dist or i >= 100-edge_dist or 
            j <= edge_dist or j >= 100-edge_dist):
        counter += sparse_grid[(i,j)]

print "%d random locations within 15 pixels of the edges" % counter
# 1579 random locations within 15 pixels of the edges
```

The error you are getting in your version is from the fact that zip is giving you tuples of x,y and not a grid of x-by-y values. You can see how your zip call should be used above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually build the array to count the edge spots covered.  If you are worried about not counting the same coordinate twice you can just remove duplicates with a set.

```
cords = set(array)                                # set removes duplicates

counter = 0
for i, j in cords:  # or array if you want to count duplicates
    if i <= 15 or i >= 85 or j <= 15 or j >= 85:
        counter += 1

print counter, "random locations within 15 pixels of the edges"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to take your 3000 random points and see how many of them are within 15 units of the edges of a 100x100 square, the following will work:

```
sum(not (15 < x < 85 and 15 < y < 85) for x, y in array)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that  Python's boolean values `True` and `False` also have integer values (1 and 0, respectively). So you can sum up a sequence of `True`s and `False`s to get a count of the true values.

I used a negated expression because it allowed me to to use Python's inequality chaining for the actual boundary testing. The expression `not 15 < x < 85` seems much nicer to me than the equivalent `x <= 15 or x >= 85`. This may be subjective, and your mileage may vary.

Comment: I don't know that depending on True to evaluate to 1 is a good idea.

Comment: @cmd In Python it's pretty safe. The `bool` type is a subclass of `int`, and `True == 1 and False == 0` is pretty fundamental to its definition. Maybe Python 4 will break that, but I wouldn't expect it to happen any time before then.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = numpy.array(x)
y = numpy.array(y)
counter = ((x<=15) | (y<=15) | (x>=85) | (y>=85)).sum()
```